# currentState of GlobalKey is null in flutter

Tags: flutter

In the following code contains three widgets with the structure: `ShowEventPage -> ChildWidget -> EventUserLists`. I want to call a method of EventUserLists in ShowEventPage when a menu item is selected. Therefore I use a GlobalKey. But calling the method `select` returns `Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'showUserListDialog' was called on null.`. It does not make any difference if I pass the Key to `EventUserLists(key: gUserListsKey)`.

show_event_page.dart:

```
GlobalKey<EventUserListsState> gUserListsKey = GlobalKey<EventUserListsState>();

class ShowEventPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ShowEventPageState createState() => ShowEventPageState();
}

class ShowEventPageState extends State<ShowEventPage> {
...
  select(Choice choice, BuildContext context) async {
    switch (choice.title) {
      case 'Attending':
        gUserListsKey.currentState.showUserListDialog('attending');
        break;
    }
  }
...

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppScaffold(
        actions: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton<Choice>(
            onSelected: (Choice choice) {
              select(choice, context);
            },
            itemBuilder: ...
            },
          )
        ]
 body: ChildWidget()
}
```

child_widget.dart:

```
class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChildWidgetState createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}

class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return EventUserLists ();
  }
}
```

event_user_list.dart:

```
class EventUserLists extends StatefulWidget {
  EventUserLists(
      {Key key})
      : super(key: key);
  final Key key = gUserListsKey;

  @override
  EventUserListsState createState() => EventUserListsState();
}
...
```